# Android page-curl in landscape orientation (how calendar)

Tags: android, opengl-es, page-curl

I use https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

Can I show page curl in landscape orientation in portrait activity. (How calendar)?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple,comment code like below:

```
private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
        @Override
        public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
//          if (w > h) {
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
//              mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
//          } else {
//              mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
////                mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
//          }
        }
    }
```